# Get parent element based on value of child element

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XDocument object where I am trying to get the direct parent element based on a child element's value.

Getting the child element's value has been no issue, but I am struggling with finding the correct way to get only the parent element. Having not worked with XML much, I have a suspicion that the solution is simple and I am overthinking it.

Essentially, based on the below XML, if `<Active>true</Active>` then I want the direct parent element (i.e. `<AlertNotification>`) and no other elements.

Thank you in advance.

**An example of the XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Policies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLschema">
    <PolicyID>1</PolicyID>
    <EmailNotification>
        <Active>false</Active>
    </EmailNotification>
    <AlertNotification>
        <Active>true</Active>
    </AlertNotification>
    <AlarmEnabled>
        <Active>false</Active>
    </AlarmEnabled>
</Policies>
```

Comment: But `AlertNotification` does not contain any data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thinks you should replace the `utf-16` in the first line to `utf-8`. Then you may try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(your file);

var elements = doc.Descendants("Active")
                  .Where(i => i.Value == "true")
                  .Select(i => i.Parent);
```

Comment: This method extracted `<AlertNotification><Active>true</Active></AlertNotification>` but I was able to extract just the parent element from there. Thank you!